# How to set a background image on the user's phone from a url

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a GridView where I'm loading a bunch of images with Picasso library with urls.

[image]

What i'm looking for is a way to allow to the user pick up the image and then set the image picked as a background on the user's phone.

The only thing that i need to know is how take that url (i have that url picked as string already) and set it as background in the user's phone.

I'm working with Android Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you'll need to download that image and get its bitmap, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24682389/1117696)

Then you can call WallpaperManager to set the background, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20054193/1117696)

Comment: Thanks. Now I have setted the background from that url into the user's phone, i send you a screenshot. Happy crhistmas. https://imgur.com/a/dXKZ35h

Answer (score 1):

Use an image loading library like Picasso. With Picasso all you need to put into your click listener is:

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    uiHandler.post(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bitmap result=Picasso.with(context)
                  .load(imageURL)
                  .get();

         WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
                try {
                    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi. I'm getting the next error with your code: _Method call should not happen from the main thread_

Comment: Picasso use asynchronous call so you can us this code in another thread (Check updates)